# How to assign formated value to other variable in xslt

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($temp1,';')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

where `temp1="fassdf sdf; asdf &amp;dfsdfsdf;fsdfsf;"`

The above code I am using to split value using ";". The problem is temp1 having `&amp;`, so it splits this value by the escaped sequence character ;. So i am getting wrong output. But if I use the `disable-output-escaping="yes"` then the `"&amp;"` is converted to &.

How to get the formatted value from the string? So if i split the string i will not get any issue. Because I will get string with & instead of `&amp;`

Comment: what you want as output? please mention desired output, we can help you :)

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting from above mentioned code???

Comment: How `temp1` is defined? If it is set in your XSLT, or manually written XML file, you have to take care of XML syntax. When you define it like `value="&amp;"` - it will have only `&` inside, because of standard XML escaping.

Comment: the temp1 having value temp1="sharepoint; R &amp;D;Department;" So it has to display sharepoint \n R & D \n Department. But R & D having value R&amp;D do R is displaying in seperate line and  &D is displaying separate line. i need out put in three differnet line.

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan, would you like to let us know which is your parser, if you know :)

Comment: @DRCB, not all parsers have this behavior, example: msxml :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume a sample XML for your/our convenience ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <child>sharepoint; R&amp;D;Department;</child>
</root>
```

XSLT code to output the desired one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:call-template name="SplitString">
      <xsl:with-param name="StringVal" select="concat(.,';')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="SplitString">
    <xsl:param name="StringVal"/>
    <xsl:variable name="first" select="substring-before($StringVal, ';')" />
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($StringVal, ';')" />

    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($first)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />

    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="SplitString">
        <xsl:with-param name="StringVal" select="$remaining" />
      </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the Output you get:

```
sharepoint
R&D
Department
```

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan, Do you want me to explain the code? or are you fine with it?

Comment: This code isn't bad (+1). The only thing is that DOE isn't necessary and should be best removed.

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan, Have thousands of them :) Designed to be robust :D

Comment: @Ayyappan.Anbalagan, Fixed a small bug :) please test now and let me know if anything you need.